# Is it possible to keep a MYSQL session open?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is it possible to keep a SQL connection/session "open" between PHP program iterations, so the program doesn't have to keep re-logging in?

I've written a PHP program that continually (and legally/respectfully) polls the web for statistical weather data, and then dumps it into a local MYSQL database for analysis. Rather than having to view the data through the local database browser, I've wanted to have it available as an online webpage hosted by an external web host.

Not sure of the best way to approach this, I exported the local MYSQL database up onto my web host's server, figuring that because the PHP program needs to be continually looping (and longer than the default runtime, with HTML also continually refreshing its page), it would be best if I kept the "engine" on my local computer where I can have the page continually looping in a browser, and then have it connect to the database up on my web server and dump the data there.

It worked for a few hours. But then, as I feared might happen, I lost access to my cPanel login/host. I've since confirmed through my own testing that my IP has been blocked (the hosting company is currently closed), no doubt due to the PHP program reconnecting to the online SQL database once every 10 minutes. I didn't think this behavior and amount of time between connections would be enough to warrant an IP blacklisting, but alas, it was.

Now, aside from the possibility of getting my IP whitelisted with the hosting company, is there a way to keep a MYSQL session/connection alive so that a program doesn't have to keep re-logging in between iterations?

I suppose this might only be possible if I could keep the PHP program running indefinitely, perhaps after manually adjusting the max run-time limits (I don't know if there would be other external limitations, too, perhaps browser limits). I'm not sure if this is feasible, or would work.

Is there some type of low-level system-wide "cookie" for a MYSQL connection? With the PHP program finishing and closing (and then waiting for the HTML to refresh the page), I suppose the only way to not have to re-log in again would be with some type of cookie, or IP address access (which would need server-side functionality/implementation).

I'll admit that my approach here probably isn't the most efficient/effective way to accomplish this. Thus, I'm also open to alternative approaches and suggestions that would accomplish the same end result -- a continual web-scrape loop that dumps into a database, and then have the database continually dumped to a webpage.

(I'm seeking a way to accomplish this other than asking my webhost for an IP whitelist, or merely determining their firewall's access ban rate. I'll do either of these if there's truly no feasible or better way.)

Comment: your connecting to a remote API to get the weather data?

Comment: Your theory as to why your IP has been blocked is predicated on you correctly guessing what the response from your hosting company was.  I'm willing to be it was because you broke your terms of service for a reason you haven't considered.  I'd also suggest that any of the methods you are proposing to get around what ever rule you broke will result in the same outcome.

Comment: why are you dong anything locally at all and not all on the hosted server account? this whole approach just sounds wrong.

Comment: Easy, Peter, easy. First, I have yet to know what actually happened (as of today, my hosting company doesn't know why, either, and has to expand the investigation). Second, I'm not proposing to "get around" a rule. On the contrary, I'm asking how I can adhere to a rule (assuming I've broken one). If the rule is ">10 connections in an hour results in blacklisting", then why wouldn't I want to adhere to the rule by having the program do its work through one sustainable connection? Your knee-jerk label of nefarious motives is unnecessary and unwarranted.

Comment: @Dagon Because I can't alter the host's PHP configuration. But I can on mine, as I mentioned in the question, which is what I've needed for the program to work. Again, I'm not an expert with PHP or MYSQL, hence why I'm open to alternative suggestions for my perhaps overly convoluted implementation. If it "sounds wrong", by all means, I'm all ears for any suggestions.

Comment: @Coldblackice My comment was neither nefarious nor knee-jerk, it was simply an observation.  The class of your question can be summed up as `I did $Something, $SomethingElse broke, I don't know why it broke, but I'm *guessing* its for $ReasonA.  Can someone please explain how I can solve this?`, where $Something, $SomethingElse and $ReasonA are all vaguely defined.  Until you can come up with an actual $ReasonA (which is something you are saying your hosting company can't even do now) no-one can offer you any concrete advice which will stop $SomethingElse from breaking again.

Comment: You're looking beyond the mark, friend. The question is up top in bold. Someone actually even answered it. (see below)

Comment: `echo "Is it possible to keep a MYSQL session open?"`, (if you need it in class form)

Comment: then you should get the correct type of hosting to match your project.

Comment: What type of "feature" or package would this be advertised as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can try Persistent Database Connection.

This link explains about persistent connectivity: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php

Comment: Aha! This looks exactly like what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: this is a bad idea 99% of the time.

Comment: Why? And what's the 1% when it's not?